# Activator extending AbstractUIPlugin versus implementing BundleActivator

Tags: eclipse-plugin

When should an Activator extend the AbstractUIPlugin versus implementing the BundleActivator?

Answer (score 0):

I found this :

> All activators must implement the BundleActivator interface. Typically, UI-based plug-ins (plug-ins requiring the org.eclipse.ui plug-in) have an activator that subclasses AbstractUIPlugin, while non-UI plug-ins subclass Plugin.

(from [here - point 3.4.6](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1271257&seqNum=4))
It is from a book so there is a good chance that it's right.
Also the name does suggest it a bit...

When you create a plugin-Project with Kepler it generates the "BundleActivator" Version. I think because there is no "this plug-in makes contributions to the UI" Option as in 3.x, yet.